# Calculate largest possible standard deviation for a set

Tags: st.statistics

Given a set with a known cardinality, least upper and greatest lower bound; how can I calculate the maximum possible standard deviation for any set of values within the set.

As an example:

Given a set {1,50}, with mean of 25.5, the std. dev. for both members at 34.65. 
This std. dev. is the possible for a set with a cardinality of **2**, greatest lower bound of **1**, and least upper bound of **50**.

Here are some examples I have calculated by hand:

F(**2**, **1**, **50**) = 34.65 (as above)

F(3, 1, 50) = 28.29

F(4, 1, 50) = 28.29

F(5, 1, 50) = 26.84

F(6, 1, 50) = 26.84

F(7, 1, 50) = 26.19

F(8, 1, 50) = 26.19

Comment: Are you allowed to repeat values? Does the set {1,1,50} have two or three elements?

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, the standard deviation should be greatest for a distribution which is bimodal: for your example, as many occurrences of 1 as of 50.  If so, should this not simplify the calculation for you?  Gerhard "Not Sure About His Statistics" Paseman, 2010.12.14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample deviation is maximized when half of the observations are at each extreme.  If you want a formula for the maximum standard deviation as a function of the interval endpoints and the number of samples, you will probably want to divide the formula up depending on whether the number of samples is even or odd.

Comment: There is also a stats stackexchange if I am not mistaken, where this question may be more appropriate.